# multiprocessing Process wont change object attributes

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement the following code using the multiprocessing package -

```
 from multiprocessing import Process from manna_1D import Lattice,info
 import numpy as np import time

 L = 2**3 N = 2**4 propagation_time = 3 cores = 1

 lattice = Lattice()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     #info('main line')
     lattice.set_length(L)

     # initialize lattice
     print("initialization process")
     for p in range(cores):
         print("started %s process" % int(p+1))
         p = Process(target=lattice.add_particles, args=(N,)) 
         p.start()
         p.join()
     print(lattice.sites)
```

I also have a Lattice class -

```
import os #for processing analysis

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

import numpy as np

class Lattice:
    sites = []
    length = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.sites = [0]*self.length 

    def set_length(self,length): #setting a length initalizes all the sites values to zero
        self.length=length
        self.sites = [0]*self.length 

    def add_particles(self,n):
        if (self.length > 0):
            print(info("add %s particles" % n))
            for p in range(n):
                loc = np.random.randint(self.length-1)
                self.sites[loc]+=1
                print(loc,self.sites[loc])
        else:
            print("cannot add particles on a lattice without sites")
```

The problem is that when I run main.py I am getting the following output-

```
initialization process
started 1 process
add 16 particles
('module name:', 'manna_1D')
('parent process:', 17850)
('process id:', 29319)
None
(2, 1)
(3, 1)
(0, 1)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(6, 1)
(6, 2)
(6, 3)
(0, 2)
(6, 4)
(4, 1)
(5, 1)
(4, 2)
(5, 2)
(4, 3)
(4, 4)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

which shows in the tuples to which site particles were added on the left and the amount of particles of that are currently in that site on the right. At the end, an output of the number of particles at each site is printed. It shows that all the sites are empty.

I believe it to be some kind of misuse of the Process object but can say for sure. Help and insights will be much appreciated!

Comment: Processes doesnt share memory, so each of them are using a single copy of the original object

Comment: can you recommend on a solution to use processes to update the sites attributes of my object?

Comment: take a look at how to communicate processes: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue